# Cross fading sounds after event in Flash CS5

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, flash-cs5

I am looking to cross-fade two sound files after an event (such as a button press) in Flash CS5.
Ideally, the first sound loops round until a button press at which point a fade out will begin with sound 2 simultaneously fading in. I have a pretty limited understanding of actionscript 3 .
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this effect you will need to use two soundChannels.  Since your using cs5 I am assuming your are looping your first sound file like so (and if not you should be):

```
var sc1:SoundChannel = myFirstSound.play(0, 999);
```

now when the event is called (button is clicked) you will want to decrease the volume of the first sound file and increase the volume of the second sound file. To do this you can use the soundTransform property on your soundChannels. this would be an example of decreasing the volume.

```
sc1.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(sc1.soundTransform.volume - .1, 0);
```

you would decrease the volume of the first sound file like this in an enterframe loop.  also in this loop you would need to increase the volume of the second sound file:

```
var sc2:SoundChannel = mySecondSound.play(0, 999);
sc2.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0, 0);
```

then inside the enterframe loop to increase the second sound it would be the same as above, but addition instead of subtraction:

```
sc2.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(sc2.soundTransform.volume + .1, 0);
```

the .1 in this case is how fast to fade the sound.  you may have to play around with that.  and once the first sound files volume hits zero you should remove it and end the loop.  Anyways, I think this is enough information in order to complete your goal. good luck.